# Extract All Named Ranges Into A Class

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a very large amount of named ranges (well over 200). I really need a way to work quickly and easily with all of the named ranges so I can then work with / populate them using VBA.

My solution up until now has been to have code inside a bunch of `get properties` in my public `NamedRanges` module, to set the property equal to the named range, like so:

```
Public Property Get LotNumber49() As range
    Set LotNumber49 = Common.GetRange(Strings.LotNumber49)
End Property
```

Where `Strings.LotNumber49` is a property which contains the name of the named range as recorded in the workbook, and `Common.GetRange` is a method that returns a new instance of the desired range object.

While this solution works well (I can now access an instance of that named range  by calling `NamedRanges.LotNumber49`) It is definitely time consuming and tedious to type up the property in the `Strings` class and another property in the `NamedRanges` class.

Is there a better way to accomplish this quick referencing of named ranges that anyone can think of? Perhaps iterating over the collection returned by the `Workbook.Names` property?

Thank you all, I have this workbook to work on as well as four others, which means a whole lot of named ranges!

Comment: Named ranges are generally used to solve the problem of organizing areas of a spreadsheet that have more meaning than `B2:C56`.  They have the nice property of being available in Excel and VBA by name.  I think if you are needing a system that manages (and renames?) the named ranges, you might have a different problem than how best to manage the named ranges.  If you find you must go down this path, I would build a new `Sub` that outputs all of the named ranges in a format that is valid VBA syntax. You can even import/add that generated code to your VBA project.  Run the `Sub` and voila!

Comment: Can you share a little more about how you ended up in this position of needing the secondary system to manage the named ranges?  I think most folks' first question here will be `"Why?"`.

Comment: Do you really need a distinct Property for each range?  Why not call `Common.GetRange` directly?

Comment: @Byron Thanks for the input. The instances help me avoid dimming a local variable and calling `Common.GetRange` in each function that I need that range object, which makes for cleaner code. Now all of my ranges are stored in a VBA module, which I think is easier.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm just trying to streamline code. I am replacing `dim lotNumber49 as range`, `set lotNumber49 = Common.GetRange(Strings.LotNumber49)` with `NamedRanges.LotNumber49`

Comment: @BGeorge "which I think is easier" until a named range name changes or you add a named range then your whole program is broken. and you have referenced to this named range everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Get Named Range by String

Why not a simple procedure like so:

```
Function GetNR(namedRange as String) as Range
 Set GetNR = ActiveWorkbook.Names(namedRange).RefersToRange
End Function
```

Then simply get the named range like so:

```
Sub Example()
  Debug.Print GetNR("NAME").Value
End Sub
```

### Named Range Suggestion in VBA Project

**Alternatively** if you want the names to popup in your VBA project you need to redefine the Constants in the `Strings` class. Try this procedure:

```
Sub GetAllNames()
 Dim res As String, n As Name
 For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(n.Name, "!") = 0 Then res = res & "Const " & n.Name & "=""" & n.Name & """" & vbNewLine
 Next n
 Dim fFile As Long
 fFile = FreeFile
 Open "out.txt" For Output As #fFile
 Print #fFile, res
 Close #fFile
End Sub
```

You need to repeat this occasionally when modifying the named ranges:

1. Run the `GetAllNames` procedure
2. Open the `out.txt` file
3. Copy the outputs to your `Strings` class or whatever

Now to get a named range use your `Common.GetRange` method along with your `Strings` name or simply use the approach above to generate also the `Getter` code like so:

```
Sub GetAllGetters()
 Dim res As String, n As Name
 For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(n.Name, "!") = 0 Then res = res & "Public Property Get " & n.Name & "() As range" & vbNewLine & "Set " & n.Name & " = Common.GetRange(Strings." & n.Name & ")" & vbNewLine & "End Property"
 Next n
 Dim fFile As Long
 fFile = FreeFile
 Open "outGetters.txt" For Output As #fFile
 Print #fFile, res
 Close #fFile
End Sub
```

Comment: That's pretty much what my `Common.GetRange` method does.

Comment: If these are all named ranges defined with a `Workbook` scope, you can generally do `Range("name_of_range")` and get a valid `Range`.  I guess going through `Names` is more robust.   I should like the `Sub` that outputs these constants and getters since I commented on doing it that way... but something about it doesn't sit well.  Regardless, this is a well put together answer that solves the problem.